# Can't send email using email function in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, email

We have G Suite account with our domain name. And our server is Google Cloud Platform. We are using PHP for our development, we trying different code for sending mails, but cant receive any mails using mail functions, and we contact G Suite account they said all the settings are working perfectly... This issue is regarding Google Cloud Platform, cloud reject the mails.

Is any additional settings needed to implement on Google Cloud Platform to establish a connection with G suite account?

Should we have an App Engine account for sending email via code?

Any ideas on what might be happening here or what to test next?

Comment: Which cloud platform product (https://cloud.google.com/products/) and which email function? You should also update the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Disclosure: I am a product manager on Google Cloud Platform (though not the products discussed here specifically).*

Note that [outgoing connections on port 25 (SMTP)](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/) are disabled, so you cannot use that for sending email programmatically. This is probably the issue that you're running into.

Here are some alternatives, depending on what server product you are using:

- Google App Engine (GAE): use the [Mail API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/)
- Google Compute Engine (GCE) or Google Container Engine (GKE):

  1. send email via [G Suite domain](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/), or
  2. work with [one of our email partners](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/), such as [SendGrid](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-sendgrid), [Mailgun](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-mailgun), or [Mailjet](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-mailjet)

Comment: using external 'email partners' is far from convenient solution

Comment: @Cris — I added another recently-added option in my answer, namely, [using a G Suite domain](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/). Hope this helps!

Comment: @MishaBrukman I've following step by step carefully for Google Suite SMTP relay service. Not working with GCE running on centos 7 and sendmail. Please refers my question at https://serverfault.com/questions/928657/linking-gcp-compute-engine-with-google-suite-smtp-relay-service?noredirect=1#comment1203755_928657

Comment: how would one set up OSSEC email notification service in google compute engine?

Comment: @ierdna — please create a new SO question. Your question, while it is related to my answer, deserves its own answer and would be more visible to more domain experts if you create a new top-level question. Thanks!