# My ajax form is saying: Internal server error

Tags: php, ajax, forms

Unfortunately, my mailing code doesn't work, can you guys check why it isn't working?
It's a simple form for my personal resume website, but the contact entry is saying: internal server error: 500.

Can you guys look why it isn't working?

My website is a simple HTML & CSS & Javascript & PHP(for the form) and it is hosted on Apache2 and Google Cloud.

```
<?php

    // Only process POST reqeusts.
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.

        $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["cf_name"]));
        $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
        $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["cf_email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $message = trim($_POST["cf_message"]);


        // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
        if ( empty($name) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
            http_response_code(400);
            echo "Niet alles is correct ingevuld!";
            exit;
        }

        // Set the recipient email address.
        $recipient = "<mail>";

        // Set the email subject.
        $subject = "New contact from $name";

        // Build the email content.
        $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
        $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
        $email_content .= "Subject: $subject\n\n";
        $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

        // Build the email headers.
        $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

        //Send the email.
        if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
            //Set a 200 (okay) response code.
            http_response_code(200);
            echo "Bedankt! Uw bericht is verstuurd.";
        } else {
            //Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
            http_response_code(500);
            echo "Error 500 Er ging iets fout,  kunt een mail sturen naar: <mail>";
        }

    } else {
        // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
        http_response_code(403);
        echo "Error 403 Er ging iets fout,  kunt een mail sturen naar: <mail>";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Did you check the error logs for anything useful?

Comment: Coould it be because you generate that error yourself in `http_response_code(500);` A 500 error is a bit serious for that situation, try some other error there and see it its that thast causing your issue

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: Hey Guys, its a simple HTML & CSS & Javascript. So there isn't really an errorlog, or are the errors within Apache2? @RiggsFolly

Comment: `its a simple HTML & CSS & Javascript`...no it's not - everything you've shown us is PHP! And it's PHP which generates that error. So either it's generated by the line `http_response_code(500);` that you've written, or by another unexpected error. The Apache log won't show it, but PHP has its own error log file. Depending on the PHP config and depending how the error was generated (as I just mentioned) you might see an error in there. If not already done, you need to configure PHP to log errors and warnings to a file, so you have a way of finding the causes of server-side problems.

Comment: Hey @ADyson, thank you for your explanation. I think I missed a few steps with making the form, it's my first time. I made my website using HTML & CSS & Javascript and this script for the form.  I didn't make any database or what so ever, do I need to do that? I've watched multiple videos but there weren't any other steps.

Comment: No you don't need a database for this - what would you use it for in the scenario? Anyway, are you saying you didn't write this PHP? Do you know anything at all about PHP? If not you're going to have a hard time fixing this or understanding any questions we ask you about the code.

Comment: P.s. this may be a platform-related issue - read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41342100/cant-send-email-using-email-function-in-google-cloud-platform and https://serverfault.com/questions/822815/cant-send-email-using-email-function-in-google-cloud-platform

Comment: Hey @ADyson, I don't have much experience with PHP, I'm just a student learning how to code. But I really want it to work an learn so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well read those links initially. It looks like mail() will never work on the Google app platform. And I assume as a student you probably don't have a G suite account so you'd be advised to get a free sendgrid account and use that to send the emails instead.

Comment: Hey @ADyson, I do have a Google Workspace account. But you're saying that making a working Ajax form is too hard for my little experience?

Comment: If experience is an issue than I suggest removing the Ajax piece until you have a working implementation. Than work on the Ajax aspect that way you narrow your points of failure because you already know a piece works without Ajax.

Comment: I didn't say that at all. You just need to find a different way to send the emails. Explore sendgrid as I mentioned. I'm sure PHP tutorials for that will exist. The Ajax part isn't the issue. P.s. A Google workspace account isn't the same as a G Suite domain.

Comment: @InvictusMKS `you already know a piece works without Ajax. ` ... did you add this comment to the wrong question? There's absolutely no information provided which would suggest this. What made you think that was the situation?

Comment: @ADyson No, that is the correct comment. Author mentions Ajax form and Javascript. My suggestion is to eliminate both Ajax and Javascript parts of the problem. Which would make identifying an issue with the PHP script easier. Once the author has a successful PHP script the Ajax and Javascript can be added back in. This is a simple and common problem solving technique.

Comment: @InvictusMKS `Author mentions Ajax form and Javascript. `...yes they do but there's no evidence they are causing any kind of problem. The error is a server side error. Ajax by itself does not cause that. Looking at the code and at the lack of support for mail() on Google app environment then that is the most likely explanation for the issue. Debugging a server side issue is not made any more difficult by the use of AJAX, if proper error logging is in place. Your suggestion is an unnecessary distraction.

Comment: @ADyson Removing layers to troubleshoot a problem is not a distraction, but a tool. There is also no evidence that proper error logging is in place otherwise the OP might not have posted this question. I'm sorry that your view is too narrow to see that as a new developer having knowledge of a debug approach is more beneficial then someone simply pointing to a line. And yes having PHP errors shown directly on screen or have something echo'd out is much easier and quicker than running it through ajax. We can agree to disagree.

Comment: @InvictusMKS it's only a useful tool if you believe those layers might have something to do with the problem. There's no evidence of that here. And intial debugging would help you to understand that, before randomly stripping back bits of code you later have to restore. But it's all too late in the process anyway...there are better ways to test - code should be unit-testable by itself. OP should understand how to test the email sending functionality in isolation, how to test the PHP script without using a browser, how to test the Ajax code against a stub endpoint...

Comment: @InvictusMKS ...then the faff of stripping back layers wouldn't be necessary. Ideally this problem would have been uncovered before the code was being integrated. But even though it wasn't, your suggestion is still unnecessary _in this case_. `There is also no evidence that proper error logging is in place`...then OP should configure it - simple.

Comment: `having PHP errors shown directly on screen or have something echo'd out is much easier and quicker than running it through ajax.` ...if you have the Developer Tools open while the Ajax is running, or you tail the error log then they will appear on screen anyway. I don't disagree with giving the OP a debugging approach, what I disagree with is giving them a primitive debugging approach which involves re-writing the code temporarily - therefore risking introducing other issues! - and appears to stem from lack of knowledge of the proper tools and techniques available for such purposes.